# Example IncreasingPriceCrowdsale

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin

Who can give a working example IncreasingPriceCrowdsale or or find error in my code:

```
contract TestCrowdsale is IncreasingPriceCrowdsale, MintedCrowdsale {
    function TestCrowdsale(
        uint256 _openingTime,
        uint256 _closingTime,
        uint256 _initialRate,
        uint256 _finalRate,
        address _wallet,
        MintableToken _token
    ) public
      Crowdsale(_initialRate, _wallet, _token)
      TimedCrowdsale(_openingTime, _closingTime)
      IncreasingPriceCrowdsale(_initialRate, _finalRate)
    {

    }
}
```

It's can been compiled and deploy on ganache, but don't work and can't be deployed on local or ropsten network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I used [this](https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6) example, and revealed while transaction commiting, the openingTime become false.

If anyone finds this question. Look attentively at all checks in contract, for example time, cap, etc.

Comment: how did you fix it? having the same problem...

Comment: In my case, the problem was that the opening Time was earlier than the block with Contract was written, and all that was needed was to postpone the start of Crowdsale.

Comment: i tried postponing the openTime to ``web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp + 20000`` but same problem....

Comment: As I recall, this number is in milliseconds, and in 20 seconds the start time can already become obsolete. I do not remember well, but it seems there is used Unix Time. Try using the time calculator and set a static start time for tomorrow, for the test. Also check other variables, for example, that the end time is bigger than the start time and etc.